# Is it possible to make use of the gluon field's energy to use is applications?

Tags: energy, mass, quarks, protons, gluons

As we know most of the mass of the proton comes from the energy caused due to the interactions of the quarks with the gluon fields (reference link of this statement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ztc6QPNUqls) so is it possible to use the gluon field's energy for using that energy in our daily life?

I know its a bit hypothetical but it's appreciating even if someone gives me an approx. answer because it can help me a lot for the google science fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable effects of the gluon field are in the nuclear [binding energy curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy). The spill over gluon field is what gives the strong nuclear force the attraction that binds protons and neutrons into nuclei.

We use this in our every day life through the electricity  provided by [fission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_reactor) reactions, and shall be using it in the future through [fusion reactors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER). The binding energy curve tells us whether fission, i.e. breakup of a nucleus, or fusion will result in extra energy in the reaction, carried by radiation and kinetic energy of the byproducts.

Comment: Is it possible to use the gluon field's energy to trigger a chain reaction fo anything like making such a device to use gluon energy for a solar panel?

Comment: No, because solar panels work with solid state energies of the order of kilo eV. Nuclear power (spill over gluon effects) is of order of Mega eV. Solid state is no go for the strong force, it melts.

Comment: Is a gluon field energy so strong? But gluon field is everywhere right and most of the mass comes from energy from gluons.

Comment: The strong interaction  is within the nucleon bag, because of the color quantum numbers the whole bag is color neutral. The spill over forces from the gluons come when two nucleons are in very close proximity where distortions of the nuclei allow attraction between gluons and quarks from one nucleus to gluons and quarks of another . Close proximity means values within the Heisenberg uncertainty bounds, nuclear distances in this case, order of fermi

Comment: Most of the mass of the proton/neutron comes from the four vectors of all the quarks and gluons in the sea, not only the valence quarks.